# How could I delete a .js file with a Discord.js command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

What I want to do is if I have a file called `test.js` I want to be able to run a Discord command, for example `!deletefile`, and it will delete the `test.js` file. Is this possible? If not, is it possible to do something similar but be able to edit the file instead of deleting it?

Comment: technically you can execute commands like `rm - rf` from javascript however I really don't know why you would want to do that. It's not really a good idea to delete files from a running program, if your OS even lets you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to delete a file using a Discord bot.

You can use the built-in Node.js module, [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) for this. Its `.unlink` method will remove a file. I don't think it's a good idea to remove files through a Discord bot, but the following should work:

```js
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');
const { Client } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client();

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith('!deletefile')) return;

  try {
    // change the path to your file
    await fs.unlink(path.join(__dirname, '../logs/1.test'));
    message.channel.send('File is deleted. ');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    message.channel.send('⚠️ Oops, there was an error. File is not deleted.');
  }
});
```

And yes, you can also [edit files in Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/file-system/how-to-write-files-in-nodejs/).

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I basically wanted to use it for a customization command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your keyboard, you could focus on the file using your arrow keys and then press CMD + Delete (or CTRL, respectively). Doing this, you can also press Enter to start renaming a file.

I suggest looking at keyboard shortcuts in VS Code:
macOS: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf
windows: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf
linux: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Vscode is just a text editor, if you press **ctr`** you can open the terminal and check what shell do you have, if you installed git then you probably have bash which is a linux shell. you can invest a tiny amount of time and learn bash and you can do much more than deleting a file. the command to delete a file is:

```
rm filename
```